# GCP Compute Engine Free Trial : e2-medium

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-compute-engine

I'm planning to use GCP Compute Engine. I know e2-micro is in the free trial.

Is e2-medium in the free tier also?

FYI: Region is asia-south1

Answer (score 1):

this is what [Free tier](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier/#compute) level includes in Google Compute Engine:

1 non-preemptible e2-micro VM instance per month in one of the following US regions:

- Oregon: us-west1
- Iowa: us-central1
- South Carolina: us-east1

30 GB-months standard persistent disk

5 GB-month snapshot storage in the following regions:

- Oregon: us-west1
- Iowa: us-central1
- South Carolina: us-east1
- Taiwan: asia-east1
- Belgium: europe-west1

1 GB network egress from North America to all region destinations (excluding China and Australia) per month

Comment: Can I create e2-medium? I'm not in the mentioned regions though.

Comment: you can create one, but any usage above Free Tier usage limits is automatically billed at standard rates.